# Why are homeomorphic spaces regarded as similar?

Tags: general-topology

Doing topology this morning, I asked myself a very simple question but I wasn’t able to answer it properly anymore. It was to know why homeomorphic spaces are regarded as similar ? On examples, we see that they resemble very much, but I do not see anymore why the important properties in topology are stable under homeomorphism, what are those properties and why.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: By the very definition, a homeomorphism preserves any property defined in terms of open sets.

Comment: They are similar upto topological properties.  Other "non topological" properties might not be preserved. For example $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ . So boundedness is not a topological property. The point being that as far as topological properties are concerned , it does not matter which space you are working with so long as they are homeomorphic. So for example I want to prove a topological property of a space $Y$, but I find it easier to work with a space $X$ to which $Y$ is homeo to. In that case I can just work with $X$.

Comment: Now that being said, you can just simply search google or a good textbook as to what topological properties are. Some examples are :- Compactness, Connectedness ,  separation axioms, countability axioms etc

Comment: @geetha290krm I see it but can’t prove it. Could you explain it a bit more please ?

Comment: An homeomorphism of $E$ onto $F$ is simply a bijection of the open sets of a topological space $E$ onto the open sets of the topological space $F$. Nothing to see with the structures with $E$ and $F$ excepting when they are explicit and involved. (group topologiques, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Informal answer.

If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and there is a homeomorphism $X\to Y$ then actually you can interpret the underlying set of $Y$ as the set $\{\hat x\mid x\in X\}$ where $x\mapsto\hat x$ is the prescription of the homeomorphism.

But what's the difference between $X=\{x\mid x\in X\}$ and $\{\hat x\mid x\in X\}$?...

The topologies are unaffected in the sense that:$$\{x\mid x\in A\}\in\tau_X\iff\{\hat x\mid x\in A\}\in\tau_Y$$

Apparantly you can think of $Y$ as $X$ itself except that every **element name** $x$ is interchanged for element name $\hat x$ (i.e. $x$ just placed a hat on its head).

I can imagine that this is regarded as "too superficial" because element $\hat x$ might differ from $x$ not only by its hat. Nevertheless looking at it this way helps me a lot to understand that $X$ and $Y$ are "almost the same". Not only if it comes to topologies but also other mathematical structures that are - what we call - isomorphic.

Essential is:

**The structure will not be affected if the elements only get a different nature**.

Answer (score 1):

Can you regard the sets $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{James,Bill\}$ as similar? Clearly not.
What about the sets $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{James,Bill,Charles\}$? You can think that is is the case, because you can define a map $f$ such that:
$$1 \to James$$
$$2 \to Bill$$
$$3 \to Charles$$
and then they are the same with the only difference of "notation".

But, what if we put "more structure" on the sets? For example, suppose that you fix in $A$ the natural order 1,2,3 and in $B$ you order these people by age: James is older that Bill and Bill and Charles and twin brothers.
With these structures, you cannot say that the sets are "similar". But if it happens that Bill is older than Charles then you can. So in any conversation (about ages) **you could substitute the names** of these people by the corresponding numbers and the meaning wouldn't be affected.

With topology the same happens, only that now the structure is more complicated. You are distinguishing priviledged subsets (the open sets) that give us all the topological characteristics of the space. If you have a homeomorphism between the topological spaces, all the topological properties of $B$ (all the conversations that you can have about $B$ with respect to topology) are the same than that of $A$

Comment: Thanks !
I am not sure to see why all the topological properties are preserved by homeomorphism. Why having an isomorphism that induces an isomorphism for the topologies too gives this result ? If two topologies are in bijection, are they really this similar ?

Comment: Because all the topological properties of a space can be formulated, in the end, in terms of the open sets. For example, if $A$ is connected $B$ cannot be disconnected. Because if there exist two disjoint non-empty open sets whose union is $B$ then their preimage by the homeomorphism will show that $A$ is not connected.

Comment: Of course, you can have more structure in the set (a norm, a Riemannian metric) and properties concerning these other structures are not necessarily the same in both sets. For example, a sphere and an ellipsoid with the induced Riemannian metric and the induced topology are "the same" as topological spaces but not as Riemannian manifolds.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about choosing a lens through which we see the world.

Imagine you're wearing glasses with a strong red filter on the lenses. With those glasses on, it's possible to look at two balls with different colors and see them as identical, because they are matching in red levels. Switch to blue filter glasses and they may be entirely different, but now there's a separate pair of balls which look identical that didn't before. So, we have things that are "red isomorphic", and those that are "blue isomorphic", and they're different from each other. The lens determined what looked the same to us.

In topology, that lens is, well, the topology. With our topology glasses on, we can *only* see the structure of open subsets on a set. Because continuous functions preserve that topological structure, any two spaces related by a reversible continuous function will look the same in our topology glasses. To use the common example, put a donut and a coffee mug on the table and they will look identical *in the glasses*, even though they are obviously different in "reality".

The benefit of this approach is that any topological property which we can show for one example will hold for any space which is *topologically* the same. Any theorem on donuts works on coffee mugs; any theorem on circles works on [the batman logo](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BatmanCurve.html). The ability to study a simple object in place of a complex one makes our job that much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot ^^
I totally get it, but something that stills bother me is that I don’t see why if two collections of sets (the open sets of two topological spaces for example) are in bijection, why would I be able to transport any property of the first one to the other one ?

Comment: @MaximeCAILLEUX Have you tried working an example? For instance, can you show that if $X\cong Y$ and $X$ is compact then $Y$ is compact? (Note that homeomorphism is much more than "the two collections of open sets are in bijection.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree, on examples it’s simple to see it working, but I fail to see the depth of the “much more than that”. I don’t see exactly what is preserved about the open sets by homeomorphism ^^

Comment: @MaximeCAILLEUX For example, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (each with the usual topology) have the same number of open sets, and so there is a bijection between their respective collections of open sets. But there is no homeomoprhism between them. Every homeomorphism from a space $\mathcal{X}=(X,\tau)$ to a space $\mathcal{Y}=(Y,\sigma)$ does give rise to a bijection between collections of open sets $\tau\rightarrow\sigma$, but not every such bijection comes from a homeomorphism.

Comment: For example, if $f$ is the bijection between collections of opens induced by a homeomorphism $F$, then $f$ has to be **containment-preserving-and-reflecting**: we need $f(U)\supseteq f(V)$ iff $U\subseteq V$ for every pair of open sets $U,V$ from the "starting space."

Comment: @MaximeCAILLEUX It's not *just* bijection, it's *bicontinuous* bijeection. This means both the map and it's inverse are continuous. This further implies that it maps open sets to open sets and non-open set to non-open sets. If you think of a topology like a patchwork quilt of open sets, a homeomorphism is like wrapping that quilt around two different shapes; the way all the patches link together and overlap is unchanged.